# How to make raspberry pi a wireless monitor

Tags: vnc

Like the title says I want to make my raspi be a 2nd or 3rd monitor to my main computer but wirelessly. How would i do this, vnc? or is there another way. I dont care to be able to plug up a mouse and control the host, just mirror. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your computer is connected on same local network , you can use [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).

Comment: Is there any free way?

Comment: most of the VNC servers are open source and free , here is an example https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/raspberrypi/

Comment: yeah but this makes the raspi the server, i got it by installing xtightvncviewer on raspi and VNC server on mac or http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html for windows